# Can the internal hostname be set for an ECS container on AWSVPC

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to run RabbitMQ in ECS on an AWSVPC network with EFS persistence.

The problem is that ECS on AWSVPC resets the hostname every time the container is restarted.  This results in rabbitmq starting an entirely new directory in `/var/lib/rabbitmq` so it loses all of it's persistence.

Eg: starting it once, `/var/lib/rabbitmq` will contain:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 100 root 6.0K Dec 23 13:00 rabbit@ip-10-0-12-171
-rw-r--r--  1 100 root   90 Dec 23 12:57 rabbit@ip-10-0-12-171-feature_flags
drwxr-xr-x 10 100 root 6.0K Dec 23 12:57 rabbit@ip-10-0-12-171-plugins-expand
```

The next time it starts the IP will change and everything else will just be dropped.

---

I've tried setting the `HOSTNAME` environment variable but that has no effect whatsoever.

I've tried setting `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR` but after the *second* start the container just cycles and shows no obvious error message for me to post here.

I've tried setting `RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbitmq@rabbitmq.dev.local` (a route53 managed domain name) on the container.  But that results in a puzzling error:

```
   [error] Supervisor net_sup had child net_kernel started with net_kernel:start_link(['rabbitmq@rabbitmq.dev.local',shortnames], false, net_sup_dynamic) at undefined exit with reason {'EXIT',nodistribution} in context start_error
```

The example on the [dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) just show setting the hostname.  But because this is ECS on an AWSVPC I can't just set `hostname` in the container definition.  As per [the manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html):

> **Note**
>
> The hostname parameter is not supported if you are using the awsvpc network mode.

I only need to convince rabbitmq the hostname is static.  I don't care what the domain or hostname is externally, just what the the process inside the container thinks is the hostname.  Is there any other way to set this other than the `hostname` in the task definition?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by using EFS for mnesia, setting RABBITMQ_NODENAME to "rabbit@localhost", and specifying the RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR.

```json
      environment = [
        {
          name  = "RABBITMQ_NODENAME"
          value = "rabbit@localhost"
        },
        {
          name  = "RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR"
          value = "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/fox"
        }
      ]
      ...
      mountPoints = [
        {
          "containerPath" : "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia",
          "sourceVolume" : "efs-rabbitmq-mnesia"
        }
      ]
      ...
    volume {
      name = "efs-rabbitmq-mnesia"
      efs_volume_configuration {
        file_system_id     = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
        transit_encryption = "ENABLED"
        authorization_config {
          access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.mnesia.id
        }
      }
    }
```